# Can DynamoDb range key be empty?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am looking at using DynamoDb for one of my applications.

I wanted to know if it's possible to set an attribute as range key and then leave it unpopulated for certain records(either empty or null).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can't insert an item with Range Key as empty value or without the Range key.

If the Range key is not included. You would get the below error:-

```
"One of the required keys was not given a value"
```

If the Range key is populated with '' (i.e. empty string)

```
"message": "One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string"
```

From AWS Doc:-

> When you add an item, the primary key attribute(s) are the only
>   required attributes. Attribute values cannot be null. String and
>   Binary type attributes must have lengths greater than zero. Set type
>   attributes cannot be empty. Requests with empty values will be
>   rejected with a ValidationException exception.

Comment: Thanks @notionquest. 
I was searching for the issue from many hours.

Comment: It is a very old post. Just adding the updated answer. It accepts empty for non-key string attributes https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-empty-values-for-non-key-string-and-binary-attributes-in-dynamodb-tables/

Comment: Partition key for GSI can be omitted from the record, I think LSI works the same way see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575985/how-can-i-make-a-sparse-index-if-the-key-is-always-required/48633818