# AWS - One of the required keys was not given a value

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

New to AWS, trying to put data into a table. After reading the documentation and trying to follow examples I am running into this validation error.

```
One of the required keys was not given a value
```

My code:

```
var conf = require("/directory");
var AccessKey = 'supersecretkey';
var SecretKey = 'supersecretkey';

var tableName = conf.tableCS;

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

console.log("Endpoint: " + conf.endpoint);
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: AccessKey,
    secretAccessKey: SecretKey,
    region: conf.region,
    endpoint: conf.endpoint
});
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var file = process.argv[2];
console.log("File: " + file);

var csv = require("fast-csv");

csv.fromPath(file)
    .on("data", function(data) {
        // Uncomment to see CSV data
        // console.log(data);

        var arrayLength = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            // console.log(data[i]);
            var params = {
                TableName: tableName,
                Key: {
                       RefID: data
                }
            };

            console.log("Adding a new item...");
            docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                }
            });
            // Looping through, now putItem into database
        }

    })
    .on("end", function() {
        console.log("done");
    });
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564832/can-dynamodb-range-key-be-empty), but am not understanding the `range` key part. I'm creating the table in this following code and have the `hash` key, but not a `range` key. Is that my issue? What would I make the range key?

```
var conf = require("/directory");
var AccessKey = 'supersecretkey';
var SecretKey = 'supersecretkey';

var tableName = conf.tableCSV;

// Take input from command line
process.argv.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
    console.log(index + ': ' + val);
});

console.log("Table: " + tableName);

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

console.log("Endpoint: " + conf.endpoint);
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: AccessKey,
    secretAccessKey: SecretKey,
    region: conf.region,
    endpoint: conf.endpoint
});
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    KeySchema: [{
        AttributeName: 'RefID',
        KeyType: 'HASH'
    }],
    AttributeDefinitions: [{
        AttributeName: 'RefID',
        AttributeType: 'S'
    }],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    }
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, table) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("TABLED CREATED");
        console.log(table);
    }
});
```

Comment: The OP edited the code above to fix the issue highlighted by the accepted answer, so now the accepted answer doesn't make sense. I don't know why this seemed like a good idea.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the table definition, you named the key `Ref-ID` but in your put operation you are naming the key `Info`. If your table has a hash key named `Ref-ID` then every record you insert will require a value for `Ref-ID`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made the changes and am still getting the same error. I edited my post to reflect the changes I made, perhaps I made another trivial mistake?

Comment: Did you recreate the table after changing the key name?