# One of the required keys was not given a value

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb

[AWS - One of the required keys was not given a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724322/aws-one-of-the-required-keys-was-not-given-a-value)

On this topic they answered that i need to recreate the table but I don't know how to do that, in addition when I enter to me Dynamo shell I see that the table description is expecting the key values that I send so i'm confused.

this is my code in python

```
item = dict(
    uaid=hasher(uaid),
    data=data,
)

self.table.put_item(data=item, overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you created your table, you defined a partition or sort key on the table that is not present in your `item` above. You need to make sure the Primary Key attribute names are present and spelled correctly in `item`.

Comment: It appears that the values didn't go trough the function that's why it complains

Comment: Please paste the result of [`print self.table.key_schema`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.key_schema) here. I want to confirm the attribute names of your table schema.