# Amazon Aws iot dynamo db insert

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, iot

I am trying to update DynamoDB and I send JSON data from Rasperry PI 2, but when I look to CloudWatch I see below error message.

Does anyone come across this error and aware of any solution?

```
2016-10-09 19:19:56.162 TRACEID:d898d574-2181-e999-4354-1d086e66ba32 PRINCIPALID:bf0e71506eb955a89d3a1cf7caecd33a3af27c13a4e560c5fa852f1d5d89a8e0 [ERROR] EVENT:DynamoActionFailure TOPICNAME:easyprk/sensorData CLIENTID:easyprk MESSAGE:Dynamo Insert record failed. The error received was One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain a null or empty binary type. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 0PNKCG5DO7SRFP49SOJIDSKD7RVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG). Message arrived on: easyprk/sensorData, Action: dynamo, Table: sensorData, HashKeyField: serialKey, HashKeyValue: , RangeKeyField: None, RangeKeyValue: 1476040796073
```

Comment: Did you look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564832/can-dynamodb-range-key-be-empty

Comment: thank you ,this link is very helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for help,comments is helpful for me,dynamoDb range key cannot be null.
when i changed nosql columns through not empty.it works now i can get data from rasperry pi :)

Answer (score 1):

When inserting items to DyanmoDB you need to make sure you dont have any empty/null attributes.